# Creating CSS animations for a smooth transition effect on hovering over element?

Tags: css, hover, transition

Create CSS animations for a smooth transition effect on hovering over element, means while hovering on element the transition should come.

I am unable to create **smooth animation/transition effect** on hovering, i want to make a smooth and clean hover effect while hovering on element.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) using the `<>` icon.  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)

Comment: Have you looked into CSS transition/transform and/or animation?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use `transition` property to add smooth transitions to elements: [CSS Transition Property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transition)

One example:

```css
.normal {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #ddd;
  text-align: center;
}

.smooth {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: black;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  transition: width 3s;
}

.smooth:hover,
.normal:hover {
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="normal">Normal Transition</div>
<div class="smooth">Smooth Transition</div>
```

Or you can use CSS animations: [CSS Animations](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_animations/Using_CSS_animations)

```css
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  text-align:center;
}

div:hover {
  animation-name: animation1;
  animation-duration: 3s;
}

@keyframes animation1 {
  from {
    width: 100px;
  }
  to {
    width: 200px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div>Hover</div>
```